# I am learning reactjs. So as I was into firebase config and after I finished I got a blank react screen

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

after i have installed these:

```
npm install firebase
npm install firebase-tools
```

**This was my firebase file before**

```
 import firebase from "firebase";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyA9BnlX96fMf7XiUVCFRsoQzG8DGERJkeY",
  authDomain: "disneyplus-clone-a33d5.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "disneyplus-clone-a33d5",
  storageBucket: "disneyplus-clone-a33d5.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "37918794208",
  appId: "1:37918794208:web:dbe9842dfe1dda522a4b85",
  measurementId: "G-DRVLJKWRWG",
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
const storage = firebase.storage();

export { auth, provider, storage };
export default db;
```

**THIS IS WHERE IM TRING TO USE IT**

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import ImgSlider from './ImgSlider';
import Viewers from './Viewers';
import Movies from './Movies';
import { db } from '../firebase';
import Detail from './Detail';

function Home() {

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("movies").onSnapshot((snapshot)=>{
      console.log(snapshot);
    })
  }, [])
```

After doing some searches, I was advised to change to firebase v9.12.1, of which it changed my firebase file to look like this:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyA9BnlX96fMf7XiUVCFRsoQzG8DGERJkeY",
  authDomain: "disneyplus-clone-a33d5.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "disneyplus-clone-a33d5",
  storageBucket: "disneyplus-clone-a33d5.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "37918794208",
  appId: "1:37918794208:web:dbe9842dfe1dda522a4b85",
  measurementId: "G-DRVLJKWRWG",
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
const storage = firebase.storage();

export { auth, db, provider, storage };
```

I am still getting the blank react screen, what might be the problem, or what am I not grasping? Thanks.

Comment: Please mask the firebase Config. It is not a good idea to expose the details here. Provide dummy values

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you are getting a blank screen, your browser's console likely has information as to why. Are there any errors there that you can add to your question? Also, to clarify @JohnBrookfields' statement, the Firebase config data is not sensitive as its publicly accessible and needed for the SDKs to work. However, I do support not posting it here unobfuscated because you likely haven't yet tightened up your security rules properly.

Comment: THANK YOU @samthecodingman your comment has aided me to know where the problem is.

Comment: also, thank you  @JohnBrookfields for that.